Is there an option to deploy streamlit application without using any cloud platform?
I have a developed streamlit application for company's internal usage and relies a bit on the VPN connection for resources and networks. However, due to confidentiality protocols enforced by the company, they are prohibiting the usage of GitHub, Docker, Heroku or any other cloud platform. I am seeking guidance on alternative strategies to circumvent the reliance on the clould platform. Any links or resources would be useful.
Application is fully developed via python/streamlit.
Need a alternative approach for deployment other than Cloud platforms.

You can definetely deploy your streamlit app with nginx on a local server, some of mine have been served that way by my devops team, at which point the issue has more to do in being proficient in setting nginx a reverse proxy than streamlit itself.

Hi Hema Apart, you may find that the users at our sister site Server Fault, a Q&A site for network administrators, may be able to better help you!
